# How to use Ajax in Visual Studio 2022 / ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm try to call action method of controller using Ajax but, we are getting null in parameter.

This is my code:

```
function Load() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Attendence/GetData",
            dataType: "json",
            data:  "{'name':'lavlesh'}",
             contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(res) {
                alert(res)
            },
            error: function(res) {
                alert(res.d)
            }
        });
}
```

Same code working in Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET Core MVC, but in VS 2022 and ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC, I'm getting null.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hows your controller code?

Answer (score 1):

> Same code working in Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET Core MVC, but in
> VS 2022 and ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC, I'm getting null.

I have successfully reproduce your issue as you have a look:

[image]

Here, the way you are passing data is incorrect, `data:  "{'name':'lavlesh'}"`. Becase you already define that as `dataType: "json"` nop need to pass it again in `json format`. You can achieve in following way:

```
data: { name: "lavlesh"
      },
```

In addition, when you define `dataType: "json"` so no longer you need to specify `contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8'` in this case your data will twice converted and you will lose data while posting.

**Note:** Point that here: `name` key must be same format as your controller parameter as `GetData(string name)`

**Complete Demo:**

Let's consider you have a Controller as following:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetData(string name)
        {
           return Ok(name);
        }
```

**So we can call that Controller as following way::**

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Okay");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:5094/Attendence/GetData",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {name: "lavlesh"},
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res)
                },
                error: function (res) {
                    alert(res.d)
                }
            });
           

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Final Output:**

[image]